# Phonegap/Cordova query Web SQL Database

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I'm developing an Android/iOS mobile application using cordova/phonegap.
When my app is ready, It's going to create, if needed, the database (DB) using [Web SQL](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html).

After creation, I'm going to make a DB query to know whether a user already exists in DB or not. Depending on query result, I will either show a form to user or simply present a welcome message.

DB Initialization code (when application is ready):

```
app.db.transaction(app.initDB, app.dbError, app.queryUser);
```

If previous code runs ok, the funcion `app.queryUser` gets executed:

```
app.queryUser = function(tx){
    tx.executeSql('SELECT name, mail from User', [], app.renderUserData, app.dbQueryError);
}
```

And my function `app.renderUserData`:

```
app.renderUserData = function(tx, results){

    if(results.rows.length < 1) {
        console.log("You have NO data!");
        inputUserData();
    } else {
        console.log("You have data!");
        showUserData(results.rows.item(0).name, results.rows.item(0).mail);
    }
}
```

Inside this function, depending on whether user has associated data or not on DB, I'm going to call one of two functions that injects some HTML DOM on the page.

In the middle of any of these functions - `inputUserData()` or `showUserData()` - sometimes (seems like it's random) the code just stops executing, and calls the error callback function `app.dbError()` (from my `app.db.transaction` call) gets called with following message:

> "the statement callback raised an exception or statement errorcallback did not return false"

And it just happens while I'm testing this on my Android phone, because when using the app on Chrome dev tools, or using [Apache Ripple](http://ripple.incubator.apache.org/#) the app does what it's supposed to do.

If someone needs more info about the code, etc, just ask..

Thanks in advance for the help.

**EDIT**

There is `app.dbQueryError()`

```
app.dbQueryError= function(err){
    console.log("QUERY ERROR: " + err.message + "\nCode=" + err.code);
}
```

Comment: It's not a Samsung phone is it?

Comment: can we have a look at app.dbQueryError too?

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest no, its a LG L65 phone. Already add app.dbQueryError().

Comment: Is that app.dbQueryError() correct? You have only called it "app.dbError" in the EDIT above.

Comment: You say that the code seems to stop in either `inputUserData` or `showUserData`? Can you try wrapping these functions in a try...catch to see if any meaningful errors are being thrown?

Comment: yes it is correct.. 
My mistake editing the question. Sorry..

Comment: I will see if try...catch gives any meaningfull errors and i will post it in here.
Thanks

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest thanks for the advice, try...catch give me another error, and with that i could understand whats going on. 
Latter I will explain what is going on to the code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :o)